# What is an index and type(index type) in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the context of **elastic search**, am I right understanding that:

-> An `index` is equivalent to a `database`

-> An `index_type` is equivalent to a `NoSQL` collection or a `SQL` table

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025876/what-is-an-index-in-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you understand it right.

**Index** is something like database.

**type** is more like sql table than like NOSql collection. Because in NoSql you can mix fields types while in Elasticsearch you must keep field within same type.

In Es there is also [some recommendation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping.html) how you should store types inside of index

From document

Good: `kitchen` and `lawn-care` types inside the products index, because the two types are essentially the same schema.

Bad: `products` and `logs` types inside the data index, because the two types are mutually exclusive. Separate these into their own indices.